# Get EditText content in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I am displaying one custom ListView using BaseAdapter. It has EditText and Button in one raw. Like this : [image]

Now I want to get text of 1st EditText when 1st Button is clicked, text of 2nd EditText when 2nd Button is clicked and so on.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2):

you need to implement  `onListItemClick`.  onListItemClick is called when you click on an element of your `ListView`. The second parameter of this callback is a `View` instance - The view that was clicked within the ListView. You can use this you to look for your `EditText` (through view.findViewById) and call `getText()` on the returned object

Comment: are you extending ListActivity? Edit the question and show your code

Comment: Yes but how to implement onListItemClick in BaseAdapter?

Comment: you have to override it in the class that extends ListActivity

Comment: I am extending Activity. Simply calling setAdapter for a listview in that

Comment: you implements onClickListener inside your adapter in order to manage buttons?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23765/discussion-between-krishna-and-blackbelt)

Comment: Hello.. come to chat window please

Answer (score 0):

The adapter has to implement the onClickListener-

```
public class YOURADAPTER extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnClickListener
```

And then set your **on click listener** in **getView** method